# Discrete Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Let $A = \displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ and for each $a\in A$, let $v(a), c(a)\in\mathbb{R}$.

Let $B = \displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i$ such that $B_i\subset A_i$ where $|B_i|=k_i<m_i$. We wish to maximize,

$\displaystyle\sum_{b\in B} v(b)$

subject to,

$\displaystyle\sum_{b\in B} c(b)\le L$

I am interested in possible methods towards solutions or literature on problems of this type.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I have edited the question for clarity.

Comment: This looks like a knapsack problem.

Comment: @Kuifje I agree, it is a type of knapsack problem, but it is not clear how optimization would be handled with the subset conditions.

Comment: I don't really see why its a problem.

Comment: @Kuifje would you mind posting a sort of answer if it is clear to you how to get equivalence to the standard knapsack problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Let $y_b =1$ if item $b\in B$ is chosen, and $0$ otherwise (assuming sets $B_i$ are already defined).

So you want to maximize 
$$
\sum_{b \in B} v(b)y_b
$$
subject to
$$
\sum_{b \in B} c(b)y_b \le L \\
y_b \in \{0,1\}
$$

You can solve it with a solver or with dynamic programming. The subset conditions are directly taken into account in the variable definitions, so there is nothing else to it, unless I misunderstood the problem.

---

**After clarification, what follows seems to be what the OP wants:**

Or, maybe you mean sets $B_i$ are not known ? In this case I would suggest defining variables $y_a^{A_i}$ that take value $1$ if item $a\in A_i$ is chosen, and $0$ otherwise. You would then maximize
$$
\sum_{i}\sum_{a \in A_i}v(a)y_a^{A_i}
$$
subject to
$$
\sum_{i}\sum_{a \in A_i}c(a)y_a^{A_i} \le L\\
\sum_{a \in A_i} y_a^{A_i} = k_i \quad \forall i\\
y_a^{A_i} \in \{0,1\}\quad  \forall a \in A_i \; \forall i
$$

This linear program creates your sets $B_i$:
$$
B_i := \{ a\in A_i\;|\; y_a^{A_i} = 1 \}
$$

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion. We wish to construct a $B$ that maximizes the sum and satisfies the subst constraints as well.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience with this problem!

Comment: Happy to help !